# UIWebView scrolls slowly in iOS9 after load 50+ times

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView App which contains local HTML files&css&js.
In iOS8 or previous,When I load HTML string 50+ times in my app bundle,it scrolls normal and not lag.
But in iOS9,when i load HTML string 50+ times,the scrollView of my UIWebView become more and more slow.

I have also create a new Project.Just to reload a local HTML String.After load many times(50~100+),the scrollView also becomes slow.A URL request can cause slow as well.

Here is my New Proj,you can run it in your device or simulator in iOS9.It can be reproduce.But when you run it in iOS8,everything is allright.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:wv];
    self.webView = wv;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.request= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];
    self.refreshCount = 0;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.webView loadRequest:_request];
    NSLog(@"refreshCount = %lu",(unsigned long)_refreshCount++);
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Hey @cube did you find a solution to this problem? I encounter the same behavior. To solve this I tried to purge the cache set the cache very small. The interesting part is, it only gets slow when a touch event is present, not while loading or switching pages. As far as I can see the touch handling itself is blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD's Or NSOperationQueues in order to Load them Quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below mention code and then try... it may work for you.

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:wv];
self.webView = wv;
```